# Numerical Methods for ODEs Precision

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have come across the following statement : Higher order (Ode stepper) does not always mean high accuracy (from Numerical Recipies, third edition). Why so ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I had to guess, it would because of the constants in front of the various terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A high order stepper represents a fit of a high-order polynomial to the values in the stepper.  Many times, these values have inherent noise from, e.g., roundoff error.  A high-order polynomial tends to treat the noise as valid function behavior and will thus propagate those inaccuracies into the final solution.  Low-order steppers, on the other hand, smooth out such noise.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it would because of the constants in front of the various terms. For example, if the error in 5th order 'stepper' is k1*h^5, while error in 7th order stepper is k2*h^7, where h is the time step, then for some values of h, it may happen than error in 7th order is higher (here k1 and k2 are constants). Basically, for fixed time step integration, this can happen.